# Why does cleaning and building android project with batch script always end with an error?

Tags: batch-file, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build, gradlew

I am trying to build android app using batch script. I have following batch script:

```
pause
gradlew.bat -PversCode=33 -PversName=2.5 clean build
echo Done building with success >>%BUILDLOG%
```

I get asked to press any key to continue after first pause but second pause never comes. That line does create an apk file but I never see Done building with success in my log file. Is there something wrong with that batch script? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

call gradlew.bat -PversCode=33 -PversName=%REVNR% clean build

solved issue.